# Angular/material crash after update to 9.2.4

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ivy

Today I've updated Angular/material to 9.2.4 from 9.2.0-next, and after ng serve I've got this:

```
platform.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/platform.js (platform.js:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/a11y.js (a11y.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js (core.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/icon.js (icon.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/home/home.component.ts (home.component.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
```

Tried to delete node_modules folder and reinstall it, what can I do?

```
ng --version

Angular CLI: 9.1.8 Node: 12.8.1 OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.11 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms ... language-service, localize, platform-browser ... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------ 
@angular-devkit/architect          0.901.8

@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.901.8 

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.901.8 

@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.901.8 

@angular-devkit/core           9.1.8 

@angular-devkit/schematics         9.1.8 

@angular/cdk                       10.0.0-rc.1-sha-a3dabc93d 

@angular/cli                       9.1.8 

@angular/material                  9.2.4 

@angular/material-moment-adapter   9.2.4 

@ngtools/webpack                 9.1.8 

@schematics/angular                9.1.8 

@schematics/update                 0.901.8 

rxjs                               6.5.5 

typescript                         3.7.5 

webpack                            4.42.0
```

ts.config

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

ts.config.app

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the tsConfig file? This error is related to the fact that something is using the ES6 syntax (most likely material), while Angular is transpiling using ES5. Actually, es2015 preset is responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi But isn't ES2015 actually ES6?

Comment: Yes, Es2015 is ES6. In your `tsConfig.json` file the `target` prop what value is holding?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi as I posted, target": "es2015"

Comment: Oh, Ok. I understand. I believe downgrading to ES5 will solve your issuse. `"target": "es2015" -> "es5"`. I mistyped before, I meant that something is using ES5 and not es2015.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Error: Error on worker #4: Error: getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected UniqueSelectionDispatcher to have an inner class declaration
after switching to es5

Comment: Mh, that's strange. Have you tried updating all the dependencies to their latest verion? https://flaviocopes.com/update-npm-dependencies/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by updating **@angular/cdk to 9.2.4** too (ot was stucked to github:angular/cdk-builds), then re-installed everything with a clean `npm i`